# Using plus sign in custom internet media types (MIME types)

Tags: web-services, http, rest, mime-types

I'm building a RESTful web service, and I'm creating some custom media types. It seems like in media types the subtype becomes more specific as you go right to left using '+'. So for example:

`application/json` is more general than `application/hal+json`, since [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) adds more restrictions on top of json.

My question is whether this is standard, or just a convention (I've poked through some of the RFCs on MIME types and I couldn't find anything, but I may not have looked hard enough).

If it is standard, does it generalize so I can add even more specific subtypes like `application/vnd.custom.mime+hal+json` or is it limited to one "+"?

Comment: For anyone finding this later, I ended up using [profiles](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6906) to specify "sub mime-type" specifications.

Comment: Could you maybe explain the thing with the profiles you mention and how to use these for mime-types in a separate answer?

Comment: In your header, you can do: `Content-Type: application/hal+json; profile=http://link.to/your/profile`
Profiles are exactly what I was trying to do with more `+` in the mime-type. They give very specialized semantics to a document. So you could, for example, specify attributes that must be in the document, and you can specify meanings etc. In hal, you can do profiles in a link like: `{"href": ..., "profile": "http://link.to/your/profile"}`

Comment: Are these `+`-denoted extensions restricted to usage in `vnd.*`-denoted subtypes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The procedure for registering new suffixes is now defined in http://trac.tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-media-type-regs-14#section-6.

"+json" will be defined in a separate document; right now: http://trac.tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-media-type-suffix-regs-02#section-3.1

And no, you are not supposed to have multiple subtypes there.

Comment: those links seem to be down, is there an alternate location?

Comment: Right you are, they work for me now. So is the best way to handle what I want to do defining something like "application/vnd.custom+json" where vnd.custom is defined as a subset of the hal documents?

Comment: @deontologician I've seen `application/vnd.custom.json+hal` and `application/vnd.custon.hal+json` as well. I was under the impression that the first one was the right way, but after looking at the draft HAL RFC, which specifies the HAL media-type as `application/hal+json`, I think `application/vnd.custom.hal+json` is probably the right way.