# extra texts in javascript mime-type (Other than several recognized js mime types)

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types

While inspecting the source code of this website: http://www.flipkart.com/ , I found this line `<script type="text/javascript+fk-onload">` . I know there are many different mime types for javascript but this one has some added texts that goes over my mind. Could anyone explain the purpose of this extra text and when can it be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`+`-suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568985/using-plus-sign-in-custom-internet-media-types-mime-types) defines a subtype. They are using it to execute that particular script `onload`:

```
FKART.utils.runOnload = function(a) {
    FKART.utils.runSnippet("fk-onload", a)
};
FKART.utils.runSnippet = function(a, c) {
    c = c || "script[type='text/javascript+" + a + "']";
    $(c).each(function() {
        var d = $(this);
        if (d.attr("data-src")) {
            $script(d.attr("data-src"), b.curry(this))
        }
        else {
            b(this)
        }
    });
    function b(d) {
        FKART.utils.evalScript(d.text || d.textContent || d.innerHTML);
        d.type = d.type + "-executed"
    }
};
```

Comment: well I think I still don't understand it fully! first thing I want to know...do we need to register the subtypes at a particular website, secondly, I didn't got the code you mentioned above, I had inspected the whole page...please guide me!

Comment: a) I don't know about mime type registration; but it seems rather bad practise to use such a non-standard subtype. They seem to expect that it is not executed as javascript. b) Me neither. However, there is a `runOnload` function with a quite descriptive name; and it does select all scripts with that odd mime type. With `evalScript`, they probably execute their contents; and if there is a `data-src` attribute they probably fetch it before by using `$script` (whatever it does).